# Get specific field values from Json Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I have JSON in response and I'm trying to get all "Id" and "Pages" values and put them to an array (or list) for next steps

```
[
{
    "Page": 1,
    "Content": [
        {"Id": 100000000000001,"Title": "title1", ...},
        {"Id": 100000000000002,"Title": "title2", ...},
        {"Id": 100000000000003,"Title": "title3", ...}
    ]
},
{
    "Page": 2,
    "Content": [
        {"Id": 100000000000004,"Title": "title4", ...},
        {"Id": 100000000000005,"Title": "title5", ...},
        {"Id": 100000000000006,"Title": "title6", ...}
    ]
},
{
    "Page": 3,
    "Content": [
        {"Id": 100000000000007,"Title": "title7", ...},
        {"Id": 100000000000008,"Title": "title8", ...},
        {"Id": 100000000000009,"Title": "title9", ...}
    ]
}
```

]

Got "Page" values by using `pages = [ e['Page'] for e in data ]` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332678/getting-specific-field-values-from-json-python)

**Can't get "Id" values**. Tried

`for el in data:
    print (el['Content']['Id'])`

But got error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Can you help me?

**Update1**: Sorry for my slightly incorrectly asked question: as output from this JSON I want to **return array ["id1","id2",...,"id9"], not print**

Answer (score 1):

using list comprehension you can do this easily

```
a = [
{
    "Page": 1,
    "Content": [
        {"Id": 100000000000001,"Title": "title1",  },
        {"Id": 100000000000002,"Title": "title2",  },
        {"Id": 100000000000003,"Title": "title3",  }
    ]
},
{
    "Page": 2,
    "Content": [
        {"Id": 100000000000004,"Title": "title4",  },
        {"Id": 100000000000005,"Title": "title5",  },
        {"Id": 100000000000006,"Title": "title6",  }
    ]
},
{
    "Page": 3,
    "Content": [
        {"Id": 100000000000007,"Title": "title7",  },
        {"Id": 100000000000008,"Title": "title8",  },
        {"Id": 100000000000009,"Title": "title9",  }
    ]
}

]

res = [[i['Page'],[ j['Id'] for j in i['Content']]] for i in a]
print(res)
```

output

```
[[1, [100000000000001, 100000000000002, 100000000000003]],
 [2, [100000000000004, 100000000000005, 100000000000006]],
 [3, [100000000000007, 100000000000008, 100000000000009]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my slightly incorrectly asked question: As output from my JSON I want to return array ["id1","id2",...,"id9"], but not print these "ID"s

Answer (score 1):

This is only an addition to the answers already given, just in case u come across more nested paths : [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) makes it easy to traverse through nested lists and dicts :

The path to pages is data -> list -> page ... so u access the data, next a list, then the page key

Same applies to id : data ->list ->content -> list ->id

In jmespath, a key is accessed via a dot, while lists are accessed via brackets([]):

```
import jmespath
expression = jmespath.compile('[].{page:Page,id:Content[].Id}')
expression.search(data)

[{'page': 1, 'id': [100000000000001, 100000000000002, 100000000000003]},
 {'page': 2, 'id': [100000000000004, 100000000000005, 100000000000006]},
 {'page': 3, 'id': [100000000000007, 100000000000008, 100000000000009]}]
```

jmespath allows u to compile a search path, similar to the functionality in python's `re` module. it's more of a tool to keep handy when you come across really nested paths.

Answer (score 0):

Your `'Content'` field is a `list`, with potentially multiple elements themselves containing an `'Id'` field. If you want to print them all, here is one way to do it

```
for element in data:
    ids = [c['id'] for c in element['Content']]
    print(ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Two more questions, if you don't mind:
1. How can I put "id" to array (don't want to print them right away)? Because now it prints array with arrays inside
2. How to convert array with arrays [[],[],[]] to one array with all values? As general output I want to get array ["id1", "id2", "id3",...,"id9"]

Comment: `flattened = [element for subarray in array for element in subarray]`